# sculpting breaks symmetry

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, sculpting

For some reason when I sculpt a model in blender, the x symmetry is broken when in edit mode (vertexes that where symmetrical before sculpting become asymmetrical after sculpting). I have the x mirror turned on when I sculpt, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Hello, either you need to apply the rotation of your object in Object mode, or your object is not really symmetrial, in that case in Edit mode select all and Mesh > Symmetrize (and set the axis in the Operator Box). If it still doesn't work please share your file:https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Having the same issue. If I go back to Edit mode and click any vertex it seems to fix it, but while in Sculpt mode, it throws vertices all over the place. At times, it will break the clipping, even if the vert hasn't moved. Seems like maybe a bug?